# how to convert xml to json using jquery

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, xml, json

The following code runs very well for [this test XML page](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/xml-to-json/data/animals.xml):

```
$.get('data/animals.xml', function(xml){
var animals = $.xml2json(xml);
alert(animals.dog[1].name +'/'+ animals.dog[1]);
});
```

But how can I adapt this code to get the rate data from [this European Central Bank page](http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml)?

Reference:

- http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/xml-to-json/#tab-Usage
- [getting data using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629042/getting-data-using-javascript)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try the following. I've tested it on FF 3.6 and Chrome 6, it works.

```
$.get('data/eurofxref-daily.xml', function(xml) {
      var jsonObj = $.xml2json(xml);
      alert(jsonObj.Cube.Cube.Cube[0]["rate"]);
});
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work: TypeError: jsonObj.Cube is undefined