# Read XML using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, json

My XML Feed looks like this

http://tinyurl.com/6wc6fel

Not sure how to read the data using JQuery and show it in HTML ?

I tried to search on Google but no great results found as you can see in my XML there are many many elements

Comment: Why do you need to convert this to JSON?

Comment: Take a look there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642789/how-to-convert-xml-to-json-using-jquery

Comment: This seems to be a good tutorial: http://www.compoc.com/tuts/

Comment: Can it be directly read using Jquery and display in HTML ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a particular reason why you need then to convert it in JSON ? you can do it by first parsing the xml data you retrieve and then create the json using [JSON.stringify](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc836459%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Here's how to retrieve the xml, you can use either the $.ajax or the $.get methods :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

//YOU CAN USE THIS

        $.get("yourfile.xml", function (data) {            
            alert('Load was performed.');
        });

//OR THIS

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "yourfile.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function (xml) {
                alert('Load was performed.');
            }
        });

    });

 </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code i figured out that its better not to use JSon because its possible to read XML using your code. I have uploaded the code here http://tinyurl.com/7sfedsy , but not sure how do i read StayDateRange(Start, End), also i want to read all elements of property tag (Id, CityCode, CityName), Address, Address1 etc in the main <Hotel> tag

Answer (score 0):

You could use the JParse Plugin

http://jparse.kylerush.net/demo