# Javascript - Loading XML into Multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, xml, html

I have been creating a game in HTML5 and javascript and have came across a problem.

The game uses a tile system to load the map. Currently my map is saved within a multidimensional array and looks like this:

```
var map = [ [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            [1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
            [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
            [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
            [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
            [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
            [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 1],
            [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 1],
            [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 1],
            [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 1],
            [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 1],
            [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

I would like to add move levels by using a XML file to update the array.

My XML file currently looks like this:

```
<TileMaps>
<Level level="1">
<map>[  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 0, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
</map>
</Level>
<Level level="2">
<map>[  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
</map>
</Level>
</TileMaps>
```

If anyone could help me load level="1" into my map variable that would be great.

Thanks

Comment: I think you should abstract your map so that it more fits into your xml ( instead of just throwing it in). It might also be a good idea to use json instead, it will save you some work from having to use an xml parsing library or parse the xml manually.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642789/how-to-convert-xml-to-json-using-jquery

Comment: @helmus What is JSON? Is it easy to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who wanted to know i fixed this by using the following code:

```
req=new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET","my.xml",false);
req.send();
xmlDoc = req.responseXML;
map = JSON.parse(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('map')[0].firstChild.nodeValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use xml, use json. Here's a link to what its about, http://www.json.org/.

While not *entirely* precise, its pretty safe to think of json as a subset of javascript.

For example:

```
{
    "levels":[ 
        [    
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            [1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 0, 1],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
        ],


        [
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            [1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
            [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
            [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
            [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
            [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
            [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 1],
            [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 1],
            [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 1],
            [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 1],
            [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 1],
            [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
        ]
    ]
}
```

Use http://jsonlint.org to validate json.

Comment: Ok so where do i save this Json code? can you save it in a file like XML or does it have to go within the HTML page? Also how would i use this code to add the information into an array?

Comment: Forget about xml completely. It has no place in this problem. JSON can be delivered to the browser in a few different ways. The first thing you should notice is that the example I gave you is a syntactically correct javascript literal object. If you want to include it directly in the page, put it in a script tag and assign it to a variable. You can also load it via an ajax request, or via a JSONP request. I would suggest that you step back from your game for a bit and read more about json itself. You can use a library like jQuery too, which has nice handlers for dealing with JSON requests.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that to me, my only problem is that i need to get this prototype finished by the end of today. I dont really have much time to read up on this. Would you be able to give me a quick rundown on what exactly i would need to do or maybe provide some sample code so i can get my head around it?