# Loop through XML in Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, xmlreader

I for some reason can not figure out how to loop through this xml.  I can get data out from the first parent nodes and the children nodes below it, but can not get it to go to the second parent node.  Any help would be great.  I'm using xmlReader.

```
function saveData(dataObject) {
        var GameData = Parse.Object.extend("AllGameData");
        var GameData = new GameData();

        dataObject.forEach(function (element, i) {
            GameData.set(element.name, element.data);
        });
        GameData.save();
    }    
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
url: xmlURL,
success: function (httpResponse) {
    var counter = 0;
    xmlreader.read(httpResponse.text, function (err, xmldata) {

        var state = xmldata.allcrosswords.StateCrossword.count();

        for(var y = 0; y < state.length; y++) {
            xmldata.allcrosswords.array[y].StateCrossword.array.forEach(function (element, i) {
                xmldata.allcrosswords.StateCrossword.array[i].game.array.forEach(function (element, j) {


                    saveData(data);
                    counter++;
                });
            });

        }
        status.success("" + counter + " row(s) inserted.");
    });
},
error: function (httpResponse) {
    status.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
}
```

});

XML is below:

```html
<allcrosswords>
  <StateCrossword UserId="223943">
    <game game_name="History CrossWord">
      <crossword_date_played>02/01/2014</crossword_date_played>
      <words_wrong>2</words_wrong>
      <total_score>110</total_score>
    </game>
  </StateCrossword>
  <StateCrossword StateCrossword UserId="4894734">
    <game game_name="Sports Crossword">
      <crossword_date_played>04/16/2015</crossword_date_played>
      <words_wrong>10</words_wrong>
      <total_score>12</total_score>
    </game>
  </StateCrossword>
  <StateCrossword StateCrossword UserId="6092735">
    <game game_name="Movies Crossword">
      <crossword_date_played>08/04/2014</crossword_date_played>
      <words_wrong>12</words_wrong>
      <total_score>0</total_score>
    </game>
  </StateCrossword>
</allcrosswords>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and post a sample of the XML you're trying to parse.

Comment: Just added, my apologies!

Comment: see this post, it should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14782408/xml-jquery-reading

Comment: Thanks Faljbour, however, due to restrictions with parse.com, I have to use Javascript throughout my function.  Thanks though!

Comment: @James Jones, I just figured out your issue, it is the xml file, you have errors in it, the second and third elements have errors.  I will post the xml file in an answer

Comment: Yup, saw your comment, thanks so much!  Still not working the way I need it too, but now it works!  :)  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to parse you xml file and found out that I can load it in the browser, so when I examined it I found an issue in the second and third StateCrossword Elements, here is the update xml file

```
<allcrosswords>
  <StateCrossword UserId="223943">
    <game game_name="History CrossWord">
      <crossword_date_played>02/01/2014</crossword_date_played>
      <words_wrong>2</words_wrong>
      <total_score>110</total_score>
    </game>
  </StateCrossword>
  <StateCrossword UserId="4894734">
    <game game_name="Sports Crossword">
      <crossword_date_played>04/16/2015</crossword_date_played>
      <words_wrong>10</words_wrong>
      <total_score>12</total_score>
    </game>
  </StateCrossword>
  <StateCrossword UserId="6092735">
    <game game_name="Movies Crossword">
      <crossword_date_played>08/04/2014</crossword_date_played>
      <words_wrong>12</words_wrong>
      <total_score>0</total_score>
    </game>
  </StateCrossword>
</allcrosswords>
```

I did try to parse it with JQuery javascript,

```
$.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "test.xml",
      dataType: "xml",
      success: function(data)
      {
        var StateCrosswords = data.getElementsByTagName("StateCrossword");
        for (var i=0; i < StateCrosswords.length; i++)
        {
          var  game = StateCrosswords.item(i).getElementsByTagName("game")[0];
          .............
        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: I failed to mention that the second and third StateCrossword elements had an extra StateCrossword tags