# Convert XML to Object using jQuery of plain javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xml-parsing

Here is a sample XML:

```
<xml id="javascriptObject">
  <name>Joe</name>
  <age>12</age>
  <gender>M</gender>
</xml>
```

Object produced after digesting the XML above should be equivalent to:

```
var obj = {name: 'Joe', age: '12', gender: 'M'};
```

You guys know any functions in javascript or in jQuery that will convert the XML to a javascript object? If none, any ideas on how to do this the best way as possible? Thanks guys!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773550/xml-json-conversion-in-javascript

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to convert xml to json using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642789/how-to-convert-xml-to-json-using-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

Try this, using the [parseXML()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) method:

```
var xml = '<xml id="javascriptObject"><name>Joe</name><age>12</age><gender>M</gender></xml>',
    xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
    $xml = $(xmlDoc);

var obj = {
    name: $xml.find('name').text(),
    age: $xml.find('age').text(),
    gender: $xml.find('gender').text()
};

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this [project](https://code.google.com/p/x2js/) ;)
this allows you to convert between json objects and XML objects