# Read every tag in XML document using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml, html, windows-8, winjs

I'm working with windows 8 app using **JavaScript**

There is a rss feed.[Click here(Look for the source)](http://www.defence.lk/news/rss20.xml). I'm using google api for get that xml content. But the thing is I can't get every tag from it like `<image>`,`<fullStory>`.. I can't find how i couldn't get them.. Is there any way for it..?

```
 feedburnerUrl = "http://www.defence.lk/news/rss20.xml",
   feedUrl = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&output=json&num=999&q=" + encodeURIComponent(feedburnerUrl);


WinJS.xhr({
    url: feedUrl, responseType: "rss/json"
}).done(function complete(result) {

    var jsonData = JSON.parse(result.response);
    var entries = jsonData.responseData.feed;
});
```

entries.entries give the each item.But the above I mentioned tags are missing. So any guide or example will really help for me... Thank you..

Comment: you can use jQuery and xml2json

[See description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642789/how-to-convert-xml-to-json-using-jquery

Comment: What do you mean in word "read"? If you have XML document you can use `document.getElementsByTagName('*')` and get nodelist with all document elements.

Comment: it seems to do something with [google feed load api](https://developers.google.com/feed/v1/jsondevguide#loadBasic). does the documentation help?